# C# how to get HTML controls created dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I generated a `HTMLTextArea` using `string` and `Response.Write()`:

```
string area = "<textarea id=\"myArea{0}\" cols=\"30\" name=\"S1\" rows=\"5\" runat=\"server\"></textarea>";

Response.Write(String.Format(area,1));
```

After this, I don't know how to get the object of this `myArea1`.

Are there any way I can achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to add `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.` will be,

```
var newTextArea = new HtmlTextArea()
{
    ID = string.Format("myArea{0}", 1),
    Name = string.Format("S{0}", 1),
    Cols = 30,
    Rows = 5
};
Page.Controls.Add(newTextArea);
```

Then you can access it like,

```
var myTextArea = Page.FindControl("myArea1") as HtmlTextArea;
```

Comment: what if the textarea is inside a tablerow

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  HtmlTextArea txt = (HtmlTextArea)(Page.FindControl("myArea1"));
  string value = txt.Value;
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487618/accessing-value-of-dynamically-created-controls-c-sharp-asp-net).

Comment: What  does `frm` refer to? Is that `<form id="frm" runat="server">`?

Comment: For more info. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296695/asp-net-get-the-value-from-textarea).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to access the TextArea object itself if you are only interested in getting the user input, which you should be able to find in Request.Form collection on form submission.